# Omit query log Sequelize NodeJs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to omit a **single** query log while using Sequelize?

For obvious reason I want to know every query shot by my NodeJs server, but I have one that is tied to a recursive function that works like a printing spooler and it's spamming my server log.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

If you want to omit logging from a plain query, use this code:

```
sequelize
  .query('SELECT ...', null, {
     logging: false
  });
```

If you want to disable logging when finding an object ORM-style, use this syntax:

```
Model.findAll({
  where: {
    id: 123
  },
  logging: false
});
```

The official documentation where this information is from can be found at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findall.